# SQL query optimization - add joins etc

Tags: sql, performance

I am not the SQL specialist. I need to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT trn.runner_id,
  tr.race_id,
  trr.position,
  trr.program_number,
  trn.horse_name,
  trc.track_id,
  tr.race_number,
  trc.ticket_name,
  trc.race_card_id,
  trn.couple_type,
  tt.country,
  tr.post_time,
  tr.sp_fav
FROM tb_race_results trr,
  tb_races tr,
  tb_race_runners trn,
  tb_race_card trc,
  tb_tracks tt
WHERE trr.race_id=514729
      AND tr.race_id=trr.race_id
      AND tr.race_card_id=trc.race_card_id
      AND trr.program_number=trn.program_number
      AND trn.race_id=trr.race_id
      AND tt.track_id=trc.track_id
ORDER BY trr.position
```

I've added required indexes but the query performs badly (~1 sec).

Comment: Add schema, otherwise we'll have no idea of your data.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: 1 sec is not( at all) bad,what you are expecting ,also share the execution plan of your current query

Comment: @JohnHC, any dbms not supporting it? It's perfectly fine ISO/ANSI SQL syntax. (However, nothing I recommend to use...)

Comment: Show us table and index definitions, and explain/execution plan or similar.

Comment: @JohnHC: It's supported by every existing DBMS implementing SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
   SELECT trn.runner_id,
  tr.race_id,
  trr.position,
  trr.program_number,
  trn.horse_name,
  trc.track_id,
  tr.race_number,
  trc.ticket_name,
  trc.race_card_id,
  trn.couple_type,
  tt.country,
  tr.post_time,
  tr.sp_fav
FROM tb_race_results trr
INNER JOIN   tb_races tr ON  tr.race_id=trr.race_id
INNER JOIN  tb_race_runners trn On trn.race_id=trr.race_id  On  trr.program_number=trn.program_number 
INNER JOIN  tb_race_card trc    On tr.race_card_id=trc.race_card_id
INNER JOIN  tb_tracks tt        On tt.track_id=trc.track_id 

WHERE trr.race_id=514729
```